# Specific select/deselect all check box code fragment not working in code but works in console

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, checkbox

```
$("#enabled-all").on('click', function (event) {
    console.log("is called");
    var enabledAll = $("#enabled-all").is(':checked');
    $("[id^='enabled-row-']").prop('checked', enabledAll);
});
```

I have this little snippet of code that is supposed to set all of the checkboxes with id like `enabled-row-` to match the header Select/Deselect all checkbox. The .on('click') function is being called when toggling the select all checkbox, as proved by the console.log, however none of the checkboxes actually change to match the status. 
The stranger thing is that when I call the .prop('checked', *bool*); in console, it works and the checkboxes do change.

What could cause this discrepancy in working code?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the jQuery code. So probably something is not correct in your HTML. Working demo below.

```js
$("#enabled-all").on('click', function (event) {
    console.log("is called");
    var enabledAll = $("#enabled-all").is(':checked');
    $("[id^='enabled-row-']").prop('checked', enabledAll);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="enabled-all">
<input type="checkbox" id="enabled-row-1">
<input type="checkbox" id="enabled-row-2">
<input type="checkbox" id="enabled-row-3">
```

Comment: I am using Datatables to generate my table which generates my cells with the checkboxes. Could it be some sort of disconnect between generating the table and creating the callback. Maybe the callback is happening first?

Comment: @DocBroc You would have to include the generated table so people can find out what the problem is.